# Refactoring binary search algorithm in Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, search

I wrote the binary search algorithm with Ruby, the code is below. The question is if there's any way to make it look cleaner?

```
def binary_search(sample_array, x, l, r)
  mid = (l + r)/2
  return -1 if r < l
  return binary_search(sample_array, x, l, mid-1) if (sample_array[mid] > x)
  return binary_search(sample_array, x, mid+1, r) if (sample_array[mid] < x)
  return mid if (sample_array[mid] == x)
end

result = binary_search(sample_array, x, l, r)
puts "#{result}"
```

It seems to me that returns can be minimised or even some more Ruby idioms added. Tried to use lambda, but smth went wrong.

Comment: If nothing else, you can make it tail-recursive by conditionally assigning a new value to `l` or `r` (or returning) according to the comparisons between `sample_array[mid]` and `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Rather than defining it at the top level, why don't you make it a new method on `Array`?
- Taking `l` and `r` makes recursive calls possible, but would be annoying for the end user who always has to pass `0` and `array.length-1`. You should either make those arguments optional, or don't use recursion, or use a private helper method for the recursion.
- Someone suggested you could make it tail-recursive, but I don't think any Ruby implementation I know of can optimize tail recursion, so I'm not sure what the point of that would be. Method calls are expensive in Ruby, so if you are after performance, I think a `while` loop would be more appropriate.
- You could consider calling `<=>` once and switching on the return value using `case`. I'm not sure if you would like the way this reads better or not. If performance is important, definitely try it and benchmark both ways.
- If you do want to use `if` statements, the 3rd `if` is redundant.
- You are using the type of binary search which has 3 different branches (depending on whether the value at the probed index is `>`, `<`, or `==` to the value you are searching for). There is another to write a binary search which only uses a single if-else, which is more concise, generally faster, and which is guaranteed to return the *first* matching element in the array (if there are duplicates).

Comment: Thanks for great pieces of advice! A lot of things to think on.